# Error 1 'Form1.CountWordsInstances(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, linq, search, text-files

I'm creating a small system that would load a text file then search for a given Search Term in a given (loaded) text file, would:
Count how many times I find these words on any loaded text. 
Count the # of lines (already done)
and many other functions, but I found myself stuck on the simple Search using LINQ.

I can't return a value because I get the error:

> Error 1   'Form1.CountWordsInstances(string, string)': **not all code
>   paths return a value**

I've tried to add some try catch statements but couldn't solve the issue.

I need to pass the content of the loaded file and the search term I want to search using the function. 
and get a count in return.

CODE

```
//STARTS Counts
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string wcf = richTextBox1.Text;
    string crules = CountWordsInstances(wcf, "rules").ToString();
}

//countWordsInstances Function
static long CountWordsInstances(string f, string s)
{
    string text = f;
    string searchTerm = s;
    string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {              
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var matchQuery = 
                from word in source
                where word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                select word;
            int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();  
            if (!matchQuery.Any())
            {
                return wordCount;
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have to return a value for wherever the method may exit.

```
static long CountWordsInstances(string f, string s)
{
string text = f;
string searchTerm = s;

string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{              
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var matchQuery = from word in source
                         where word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                         select word;
        int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();  
        if (!matchQuery.Any())
        {
             return wordCount;
        }

      }
   // Answer Mod Here!
   return 0; 
   // Or whatever value you think should be returned if your condition
   // is not met above.    
}
```

Comment: Thank TyCobb, 
That did the trick and was in my face all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`CountWordsInstances` returns a `long`, but if `f` has no lines of text for the `while` loop to iterate through, or if `matchQuery` returns any results, then nothing will be returned from the method. That's why you're getting the error.

```
if (!matchQuery.Any())
    return wordCount;
```

The solution is to rethink what you're doing. At the very least, to get the error to go away, place a `return 0` as the last line in your method.

Answer (score 0):

try catch statements have to do with *runtime* exceptions, you are getting a *compile-time* error.

Your function simply isnt quite complete. Consider the case where `while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)` is immediately false. In this case, you skip over the entire while statement and don't return a value. That's where the compiler is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there are conditions where no value is being returned by your function. A quick look at your code tells me that if `(!matchQuery.Any())` is never fulfilled then the function does not return anything, which is a big no no.

Now I'm not entirely sure how you use this function, but a `return 0` just before the function ending bracket should solve this error.

Additionally, even if you *do* successfully enter the while statment, if `if (!matchQuery.Any())` fails, you yet again do not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning within your `if` statement. What happens when `!matchQuery.Any()` returns false and you never enter the `if`? You need to return from an else or similar:

```
if (!matchQuery.Any())
{
    return wordCount;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everybody else said, and presuming that you want to read the text file line by line, perhaps a better way to write this code would be something like:

```
private static long CountWordsInstances(string filePath, string searchTerm)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        long wordCount = 0;
        var separators = new[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' };
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            wordCount +=
                line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Count(x => x.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

You can shorten this a bit further to something like:

```
private static long CountWordsInstances(string filePath, string searchTerm)
{
    // careful this will load the entire text into memory
    // might be OK if your files are not large
    string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var separators = new[] {'.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ','};
    return text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Count(x => x.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

I hope this helps, please let me know if it needs any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a compiler error. It says to you that there exists an execution path in `CountWordsInstances`, where function isn't returns a value which was declared to return. So, you just need to add `return` or `throw` statements to places where it needed. See my comments

```
static long CountWordsInstances(string f, string s)
    {
    string text = f;
    string searchTerm = s;

        string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
        {              
            string line;
// there is no guarantee for compiler that you entry in while-block here
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                var matchQuery = from word in source
                                 where word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                                 select word;
                int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();  
 // there again is no guarantee to enter in if-block
                if (!matchQuery.Any())
                {
                 return wordCount;
                }
// so compiler don't know what to return here
            }                
// and here. (also, you can add just here return or throw statement)

        }
    }
```